# Python - How to concatenate more than arrays lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I have many arrays, let's say

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
Z = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])
```

I want to concatenate them all so I have

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Here is what I've tried

```
arr = X + Y + Z
```

this doesn't work, here is my result

```
>>> print(arr)
[15, 18, 21, 24]
```

Just the sum of each element at an index `i`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code works for me. Also, don't call your list `list`, it masks the built-in type

Comment: are you sure they're lists?  `X + Y + Z` *should* give you what you want.

Comment: Based on the results, you "lists" are not lists but numpy array. Please confirm.

Comment: I run it and got what your expected.

Comment: @DYZ just checked the type. You are right, it is not a list, but a numpy array. I'll edit the question now

Comment: Then please update your question and use `np.concatenate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.concatenate()`

```
a = np.concatenate((X, Y, Z))
print(a)
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.concatenate` to combine np arrays:

```
import numpy as np 
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
Z = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])

print np.concatenate((X,Y,Z), axis=0)
```